# Getting an "Cannot open database ..." error while debugging

Tags: sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

I built a sample application using Entity Framweork 4.3 with Code-First and CSLA 4. If I run some query using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>F5</kbd>, everything works fine, but if I try to debug using <kbd>F5</kbd>, the following  SQLException pops up.

> Cannot open database "XYZ" requested by the login. The login failed.
>       Login failed for user 'Domain\User'.

I have no idea what could be going wrong because the only difference between executions is the presence of the debugger. Could you help me to find some answers to this question?